# Make FTP connection in Laravel not working with Flysystem library

Tags: laravel, ftp, flysystem

Hello i am trying to make a FTP connection, using Laravel 8 and Flysystem library, however all my tries have failed.  My ftp details work on Fillezilla

Here is my code

```
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Ftp;
```

```
$adapter = new Ftp([
    'host' => $ftp_server,
    'username' => $ftp_username,
    'password' => $ftp_password,
    'port' => 2526,
    'passive' => false,
    'ssl' => false,
    'tls' =>false,
    'timeout' => 400,
    'utf8' => false,
    'passive' => true,
    'transferMode' => FTP_BINARY,
    'systemType' => null, // 'windows' or 'unix'
    'ignorePassiveAddress' => null, // true or false
    'timestampsOnUnixListingsEnabled' => false, // true or false
    'recurseManually' => true // true 
]);



$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);


// Check if the connection is successful
if ($filesystem->has($path)) {
    echo "FTP connection successful!";
} else {
    echo "FTP connection failed!";
}
```

It is giving me always FTP connection failed! and i can't find any solution

Thanks in advance for your help

edit:

I decided to try to do a simple file upload  in a simple plain php file to check if it works,  and i am having the same problem

for this i used this code

```
// File details
$fileName = 'example.txt';
$fileContents = 'This is the content of the file.';

// Create a temporary file
$tempFile = tmpfile();
fwrite($tempFile, $fileContents);
fseek($tempFile, 0); // Move the file pointer to the beginning of the file



// Connect to FTP server
$connId = ftp_connect($ftpServer, $ftpPort);

if ($connId) {
    // Login to FTP server
    $loginResult = ftp_login($connId, $ftpUsername, $ftpPassword);

    if ($loginResult) {
        // Perform FTP operations here (e.g., put, get)
       // echo "conexão";
        // Logout and close the connection
        // ftp_pasv($connId, true);
        
        // $localFile = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\FtpTest\file\file.txt';
        // $remoteFile = '/file.txt';
        // //ftp_mkdir($connId, $remoteFile);
        
        // // Upload file to FTP server
        // if (ftp_put($connId, $remoteFile, $localFile, FTP_BINARY)) {
        //     echo 'File uploaded successfully.';
        // } else {
        //     echo 'File upload failed.';
        // }


        // ftp_close($connId);

        // Upload the temporary file to the FTP server

     //   ftp_pasv($connId, true);

$upload = ftp_fput($connId , $fileName, $tempFile, FTP_ASCII);
if (!$upload) {
    die('Failed to upload the file');
}

// Close the temporary file
fclose($tempFile);

// Close FTP connection
ftp_close($ftpConnection);

echo 'File created successfully.';

    } else {
        echo 'FTP login failed.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Could not connect to FTP server.';
}
```

If i set my passive as true i get this error

```
Warning: ftp_fput(): php_connect_nonb() failed: No error (0)
```

if i set it false i get this error

```
Warning: ftp_fput(): Illegal PORT command
```

So i am starting to believe that the problem is not exactly to my code, but maybe something with my server, however i find it strange, since i can enter it , by using filezilla

Comment: the app connection (php) and filezilla are in the same network? using command line is working?

Comment: What's the value of `$path`?

Comment: See https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/204#issuecomment-49580640 for a more resilient connection checking code that doesn't rely on the existence of a particular path (which might be wrong, or deleted).

Comment: @ceejayoz My  path  is  $path = '/';

Comment: @Tigane If you use a FTP client, do you have access to `/`? Many FTP servers drop you in somewhere like `/home/username` with no access to the root.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes, if i make this connection in Filezilla it frops me to `/`

Comment: Answering to @Jack  ,  yes the app connection and filezilla both are in the same network.    However, i tried doing a ftp connection on the windows command line  and without specifyinbg my port i get `: ftp: connect :Connection timed out`    but by specifying my port i get  a   `open: bad port number myHostname
Usage: open host name [port]  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly solved yet,  but found out where my problem lies.  It is  on my server where i am trying to send my files to.  Despite a connection was made in filezilla, just found out that it isn't allowing me to transfer files inside there (Since the connection was made, i assumed before, that everything was working fine in there).

So i believe the code i put in here, and the one that @Hercules73 suggested  works fine.  Thank you